# Making sprite rotate like clock hands?

Tags: java, rotation, libgdx, sprite

I made a sprite that is similar to a clock hand, I made it rotate like this:

```
if(condition==true){
  Sprite.rotate(1);
}
```

But as I expected it won't rotate like a clock hand, instead it would rotate the entire texture, I wan't the bottom to stay where it is and only the upper part rotate just like a clock. I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean it rotates around its center instead of its end?

You can set the origin of a sprite with [`setOrigin(float, float)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setOrigin-float-float-) and it will rotate around that point.

Comment: The origin doesn't make a difference for the effect you want. If you want it to move to the new angle smoothly over time you have to interpolate the angle over a that period of time. Essentially, for every update over say, one second, rotate the sprite a percentage of the angle based on how long it has been moving. This is a slightly more advanced topic and you could do well from reading about linear interpolation.